# Reading text from cgi.FieldStorage instance

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, cgi

I'm trying to read a tab delimited text file uploaded through multipart POST. I'm running this code on Google App Engine using Python/Webapp2/Jinja2.

I get this error in the line indicated below: "AttributeError: (two underscores)exit(two underscores)"

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to make this work? Thanks!

```
class FileReader(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def post(self):

    field_storage = self.request.POST.get("file", None)
    if isinstance(field_storage.file, cgi.FieldStorage):

        with field_storage as csvfile:    ## This line causes an error "AttributeError: __exit__"
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)

        for row in reader:
            ...
```

Comment: the line `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)` should be indented, as should everything after if you're going to be using that file. Is your indentation here accidental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

field_storage.file is a StringIO object. There is no need to open it, because it is already an open file object.

So skip the with and try:

```
reader = csv.reader(field_storage.file, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```